# C best way to clear an array of doubles

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, free, calloc

In C, How can I reset a given pointer to have all values in an array be a specified value? Is it best using a for loop, or is there a function that I can use to set all values in an array to 0.

My code currently is something like this:

```
int main()
{
     double *my_values = calloc(10, sizeof(double));
     do_something_with_values(my_values);

     free(my_values);
     my_values = calloc(10, sizeof(double));

     do_something_else_with_values(my_values);
     free(my_values);
}
```

This (to me) seems hacky, how can I improve this code?

Comment: Everyone recommends using memset to zero out memory. This works fine on all hardware where 0.0 is represented by all zero bits. Can't find where in the C standard that is required.  ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

memset can set an array to all zero's or whatever value you want

Comment: How can I do that though? (Example please)

Comment: memset(your_array, 0 (or w/e value you want), size of your_array);

Comment: so is it sizeof(your_array) or 10 * sizeof(double), because sizeof(your_array) would return 8, would it not? (on 64 bit systems)

Comment: I didn't mean literally sizeof(...), I meant the length of your array.

Comment: Why this answer is voted up if it is not correct? `memset` sets all BYTES to zero. Bitwise zero doesn't mean 0.0 float/double value. Yes, it will be 0.0 on most current platforms. But not on all. So code using `memset` or `calloc` for zeroing float/double array will be unportable.

Answer (score 4):

The code is not just hacky, it could lead to severe and difficult to reproduce bugs.

By doing a `free` and then a new `calloc` call you are NOT guaranteed for the same memory space to be assigned to your array, this could be a problem if you have a pointer to this array before doing that and try to use it later.

Comment: +1 Even though this doesn't directly answer OPs problem, the question seems to indicate OP is mistaken about `calloc` mechanics, which makes it worth bumping this to the top.

Answer (score 1):

If this is really always about fixed size arrays as in your example, you might be on the wrong track already with your allocation. Better do

```
int main(void) // <- this is the correct signature
{
     double my_values[10] = { 0 };
     do_something_with_values(my_values);

     memcpy(my_values, (const double[10]){0}, 10*sizeof(double));

     do_something_else_with_values(my_values);
}
```

The definition and initialization here ensures that the array is initialized with the correct value for `0.0` on whatever architecture you run this. The reinitialization with `memcpy` does the same. It uses a compound literal to achieve that. You'd have to have a C99 conforming compiler for that part.

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time, it was 1975, someone started to write a library for a completely new programming language called C. If you had more than 64KB of RAM you had access to one of the world's largest supercomputers.

So when routines like `memset()` were designed, no one could imagine that you might want to initialize something bigger than an 8bit byte. A byte was *huge* at the time.

If you need something bigger, you must write your own loop. On the positive side, all C types are zero when all bytes are 0. So you can either use `calloc()` or get the memory from somewhere else and use `memset(ptr, 0, size);`

Comment: Your last paragraph is true for most sane, real-world implementations but false as far as the standard is concerned. Only integer types are guaranteed to use all-bits-zero for their zero value. Pointer and floating-point types are allowed to use other representations of zero.

Comment: True but the IEEE standard (which is used by most CPUs today) says the same and also all wide-spread CPUs use the same (so you can quickly check a null pointer by loading it into a register and then branch on the ZERO flag).

Answer (score 0):

For initializations you can simple use:

```
double myarray[100] = {0};
```

Comment: This could be used only for initialisation of static arrays.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would probably be to use `memset`

```
    memset( the_array, '\0', sizeof(the_array) );
```

This will zero out your entire array

Comment: @Jesus: Mala's use of `sizeof` is correct. `memset` takes a number of bytes, not a number of array elements.

Comment: `memset` sets all BYTES to zero. Bitwise zero doesn't mean 0.0 float/double value. Yes, it will be 0.0 on most current platforms. But not on all. So code using `memset` or `calloc` for zeroing float/double array will be unportable.

Answer (score -1):

Use [memset](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/memset.html):

```
memset(my_values, 0, 10 * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: `memset` sets all BYTES to zero. Bitwise zero doesn't mean 0.0 float/double value. Yes, it will be 0.0 on most current platforms. But not on all. So code using `memset` or `calloc` for zeroing float/double array will be unportable.

Comment: C90 (Annex F) specifies that `double` matches the `IEC 60559` floating point format. That standard specifies a representation where if all 8 bytes are zero, the value is (positive) zero. If a platform interprets a double whose bits are all zero as something other than zero, it's not compliant with the standard. I don't have a copy of C99 or C11 handy, but I'd be shocked if they changed this.

Answer (score -1):

I may be completely off base here but: I would use memset.

http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man3/memset.3.php

Comment: `memset` sets all BYTES to zero. Bitwise zero doesn't mean 0.0 float/double value. Yes, it will be 0.0 on most current platforms. But not on all. So code using `memset` or `calloc` for zeroing float/double array will be unportable.